# Multimedia and Addbinary method in tridion

Tags: 2013, multimedia

I am using tridion 2013, where I need to publish the css images. It's getting published using the below templates(1 & 2) but is appending the tcm id.

Template 1 - I thought using Addbinary would not append the tcmid but it's doing so.

```
Component mmc = engine.GetObject(package.GetValue("Component.ID")) as Component;
engine.PublishingContext.RenderedItem.AddBinary(mmc);
```

Template 2 -

```
TcmUri Comp = new TcmUri(package.GetValue("Component.ID"));
Item compItem = package.CreateMultimediaItem(Comp);
package.PushItem("MultimediaDoc"+compItem.ToString(),compItem);
```

Now if I need to directly refer that image in the PT/CT like "`images/print.css`" instead of reading from the component then it's not appearing since the filename is not matching(in PT it's without tcm id and I can't use it because of environment conflict). Please suggest how to refer it correctly in my page even if it's published with tcm id appended.

**UPDATE** - I have used the same DFA along with Template 2 code to publish the binary in
             2011, it gets published without tcmid, but in 2013 only it's appending tcmid.

Comment: can you expalin why do you have 2 TBBs for it? also, are you using "Default finish actions" TBB in your template?

Comment: I have tried with both one by one to see if it gets published without tcmid, but both are having the same output. Yes I have DFF having the inbuilt Publish Binary in Package TBB.

Comment: The "Publish binaries in package" TBB, which is a Part of DFA Tbb. it could add the TcmID to the filenames to avoid conflict between the binaries having the same title. I suggest you to try Template 1 without it.

Comment: How the images will then get published to the server after removing "Publish binaries in package" TBB?

Comment: The `engine.PublishingContext.RenderedItem.AddBinary()`  function will do it for you, Please refer TOM.NET API document for more details and overloaded methods for it.

Comment: I meant in case if we use the DFA without "Publish binaries in package" TBB for images coming from component, then it would not publish instead of dynamic publishing of images. So do we need to have two DFA ver(with and without "Publish binaries in package) to address the issues.

Comment: well, I am not saying remove "Publish binaries in package" from DFA TBB (but from your template somehow), as it could be used else where. See you need to understand, DFA is tridion supplied standerd TBB which groups other TBBs. please understand the job of each TBB and use those according to your need. Not use it blindly everywhere. roughly, if your CT is just to publish CSS file dynamically, I guess you can remove the DFA TBB from your CT. But again chose to do it once you are sure.

Answer (score 4):

What you are doing in your **Template 1** is publishing the Multimedia Component using the `RenderedItem.AddBinary()` method. However you don't seem to be doing anything with the `Binary` object returned (which contains the `Binary.Url` property).

Then in **Template 2**, you are also adding your Multimedia Component to the `package`, after which the "Publish Binaries in Package" TBB will publish it using its `AddBinary()` method too. And then the "Link Resolver" TBB will use its outcome to resolve the links to your Multimedia Component. So it appears you are processing your item twice, assuming you have the "Default Finish Actions" TBB also in your Template.

Please note that there are several different `AddBinary()` methods (`RenderedItem.AddBinary()`, `Engine.AddBinary()` and `TemplatingRenderer.AddBinary()`), each have their own specific behavior and overloads. The "Publish Binaries in Package" TBB uses the `Engine.AddBinary()` method.

I'll leave it up to you to find out which one does or does not add the TCM URI, but one thing is certain, you will always need to do something with the return of the `AddBinary()` method. Else what you are doing is just publishing the Multimedia Content and you have no way of resolving the links in your original Template.

If you decide to publish the binary yourself, then make sure it is not also done via any other TBB. You can prevent that from happening by setting the published path in the package item properties (`Item.ItemPropertyPublishedPath`), see the code example below of how that can be done:

```cs
foreach (Item item in package.GetAllByType(new ContentType("*/*")))
{
    if (item.Properties.ContainsKey(Item.ItemPropertyTcmUri) &&
        item.Properties.ContainsKey(Item.ItemPropertyFileName))
    {
        // has the item already been published?
        if (!item.Properties.ContainsKey(Item.ItemPropertyPublishedPath))
        {
            // publishing item of type item.ContentType
            string publishedPath = engine.AddBinary(item, targetStructureGroup);

            item.Properties[Item.ItemPropertyPublishedPath] = publishedPath;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Originally I had the template 2, to put the mmc in package and rest of the things i thought will be taken care by the DFA's AddBinary() method. But in my case it's appending the tcmid which is not the case with AddBinary.

Comment: @user945 The Default Finish Actions does not append the TCM URI when publishing the MMCs, so if you see that happening, there is something else doing it. It could be something which was added like is described here http://www.urbancherry.net/blogengine/post/2010/02/09/Unique-binary-filenames-for-SDL-Tridion-Multimedia-Components.aspx

Comment: With Template 2 and DFA, it's appending tcmid. I have checked it in template builder and template 2 is not appending tcmid and as per you DFA is not appending as well. Why the behaviour is such in 2013 where as 2011 is not appending.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great article in this blog [CSS in SDL Tridion – Part 2: Handling image references](http://www.building-blocks.com/thinking/css-in-sdl-tridion-part-2-handling-image-references/) in which it seems to suggest what you need to do.