# Publishing binares with Default Finish Action (PublishBinariesInPackage) vs AddBinary

Tags: 2013, publishing, binary

I have the following scenario:

Master publication A on level 1 which is inherited through blueprint by Publication B on level 2 and Publication C on level 2.

I crate new multimedia component (with image pictureX.jpg) and a component that uses the image in Publication A. This is inherited in Publications B and C and image is not localized. Publications B and C share images folder on the file system (they are mysite.com/english-B/ and mysite.com/german-C/)

When I publish from publication B using template with default finish action pictureX.jpg is deployed to the images folder. I then publish from publication C, images pictureX.jpg is still there and there is no new image. So far so good.

I now publish using addbinary from publication B and C and two images are created (with suffix tcm),one for each publication. I would like to have 1 image. I can add image name to addbinary call, but this produces deployment conflict (binary with same name already exists).

How is this best solved? Should I use addbinary on image from parent publication (or first publication where it is localized)?

Comment: To avoid the publishing commit conflict you could handle image publishing (i.e. don't use Default Finish Actions). See @BartKoopman's answer to this question http://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/5312/46, also recommending to also resolve links to any images published with `AddBinary()`. I believe Publish Binaries in Package also uses AddBinary (per [Chris Summers' popular post](http://www.urbancherry.net/blogengine/post/2010/02/09/Unique-binary-filenames-for-SDL-Tridion-Multimedia-Components.aspx)), you might be able to also use a  version of AddBinary() (not sure which though).

Answer (score 5):

The reason that there are two images produced (one per publication) is because they are separate images, even if they are shared components.

At the moment your images are the same (as they are both shared from Publication A), however if you where to localize the image in Publications B and C and upload a new image to each publication the images will now be different and so should not have the same file name.

I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve and why having an image per Publication context is an issue?

Comment: I would like to see if I can reduce number of deployed binaries with the same content (the same way PublishBinariesInPackage is doing)

Comment: I think in this instance it would be safer to have 2 images and different references to them from each site.

The reason I say this is if you had both sites looking at PictureX.jpg and then later down the line Publication B decides to localise the image and publish it out Publication C would also be updated as it references the same image. 
Again if Publication C where to publish the image again Publication B would then be, incorrectly, updated too.

I think this could lead to editorial confusion especially if you have different editors managing the two different publications.

Comment: scenario you describe is not possible as localizing image (and changing it) in publication C and publishing would deploy a new binary to the file system. What I am interested in is how to prevent the same binary to be in the file system two (or more) times (which is built in PublishBinariesInPackage tbb and I want to replicate with AddBinary)

Comment: But what if the image had the same file name as the original file, this would cause a conflict would it not?
Another reason for keeping the tcm ID on the end of the image is so that as editor uploads more images you can grantee a unique image. E.g. I have seen many images being uploaded as logo.jpg in the same publication.